# Where does Sword Art Online Extra Edition fit in?

Tags: sword-art-online

I was browsing Anime News Networking getting names of Anime for searching for OSTs (because sometimes they get labeled by their original japanese name) and there was [this add](https://www.daisuki.net/saoee) about some Sword Art Online Extra Edition.

The site has a teaser and it says it's going to start streaming on the 31st so it makes me think it's not just a different type of Collections Edition (to which i have all 4 from RightStuf), just looking at the images and the teaser it seems to be set around the second arc but i'm not entirely sure.

So i'm wondering, Where does Sword Art Online Extra Edition fit in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a special that plays after the SAO-anime (after the alfheim arc). It has an original story not covered in the light novels.